# Set optional value with function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to use a type guard with a non-parameter variable. The actual scenario is a property on a class, but I've tried to simplify it with a variable outside the block instead.

```
let x: string | undefined

function fn() {
    setX()
    x.toLowerCase() // x might be undefined
}
function setX() {
    x = "foo"
}
```

More applicable example:

```
class FooWidget {

    private el: Element | undefined

    public display() {
        this.createElementIfNotExists()
        this.el.classList.add("display") // this.el possibly undefined
    }

    private createElementIfNotExists() {
        if (this.el) return
        this.el = document.createElement("div")
        document.body.appendChild(this.el)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused; if you have a variable of type `string | undefined` you need to check it before dereferencing it.  Like `x?.toLowerCase()` or `if (typeof x === "string") x.toLowerCase()` or any other applicable method.  I must be missing something about the question.  Are you really looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLXeZm) or is there more going on here?  If there's more going on, could you [edit] to elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the response @jcalz -- added another example based on what I'm doing. The widget lazy-creates an element to avoid polluting the DOM, but because of the logic, the element will always exist, and I was hoping TS would infer that, or that I could create a guard (or predicate?) that would explicitly narrow the variable as not-undefined.

Comment: You can make the method return [an `asserts` predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2kL8N) but it only works with public (and maybe protected) properties, not private ones.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks @jcalz I've never used asserts-- exactly what I was looking for. Slightly awkward having to make the property public but that seems like a small price to pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createElementIfNotExists()` method doesn't return a value, but after it is called, the type of the `el` property should be known to be `Element` instead of `Element | undefined`.  That means you can turn it into an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) which [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of the object on which it is called.  Assertion methods have a return type of the form `asserts this is ⋯`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
  protected el: Element | undefined // can't be private

  private createElementIfNotExists(): asserts this is { el: Element } {
    if (this.el) return
    this.el = document.createElement("div")
    document.body.appendChild(this.el)
  }
```

Once `this.createElementIfNotExists()` is called, `this` is narrowed to `this & {el: Element}`, which is enough for your code to start working:

```
  public display() {
    this.createElementIfNotExists()
    this.el.classList.add("display") // okay
  }
```

Note that for this to work the `el` property can't be [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#49709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49709)).  There's no way to write `asserts this.el is Element`, and the type `{el: Element}` implies `public` in a way that's incompatible with a `private` property.   You *can* make it [`protected`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#protected), though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28DqBLAJgcwKYBdoG8AoQ6aABwCd4ctga1osQAuaAURCwFssA7PAD7QArrzRYAZil5YGAejnRgYXgHI8AIyzkKKAG5gaxUmWEaQKYNDQoIZcAE8AFAEoCJUtBwALWwDpgCixDLA5uPhwASQkAOWo2AA9bHAhXD1IffyYA8CgAGWS-MDQ0JwAiGztHMrcFaHgAazAHDwBfYx19EKUgkLCefmi4nETk1JdWSAgsChSvXxhbAkYWdk4BvFb3T2gUCWgnTIg-JjcgnGEKXnT5rJBoAF5reGBhDYDemn6I8ps9GpuaBebwifg08DQDiKZDIfDQAGFfCBSkcTiAXG1CK0gA)